# Is there a way to save the acceptance rate of the MCMC algorithm used by MCMClogit?

Tags: r, mcmc

The `R` package `MCMCpack` offers Bayesian logistic regression through `MCMClogit`. This function prints the acceptance rate of the MCMC (Metropolis-Hastings) algorithm if `verbose=TRUE` but it does not seem to return it in the `mcmc` object. Is there a way to access this information in the object?

To test use:

```
    library(MCMCpack)
    set.seed(12345) 
    n = 1000 
    x = rnorm(n) 
    y = rbinom(n,1,1/(1+exp(-(1 + x))))
    m = MCMClogit(y ~ x, burnin = 5000, mcmc = 1000,
                         tune = 1.3, B0 = 0, verbose = TRUE)
```

Which prints an acceptance rate of `0.45533` but I do not find this information in `names(m)` returning `NULL` or `names(attributes(m))` which returns

```
[1] "dim"      "mcpar"    "class"    "dimnames" "title"    "y"        "call"
```

The help file suggests that the `coda` package allows sumarizing information from `mcmc` objects (see [coda](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/coda.pdf)) but searching for 'acceptance' in the pdf does not yield any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the behavior of `capture.output`, you can use `sink` instead, which still returns the results but redirects the console output into a file.

```
sink(file="test.txt")
m <- MCMClogit(y ~ x, burnin = 5000, mcmc = 1000,
               tune = 1.3, B0 = 0, verbose = TRUE)
sink()

out <- readLines("test.txt")
grep( "acceptance rate for beta was", out, value=T)
# [1] "The Metropolis acceptance rate for beta was 0.45533"

class(m)
# [1] "mcmc"
```

No need for `assign` or `<<-`.

If you want to have it as a numeric value, you can extract it as follows.

```
ar <- grep( "acceptance rate for beta was", out, value=T)
ar <- as.numeric( gsub("^.* was (.*)", "\\1", ar) )
ar
# [1] 0.45533
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would not save the value of the acceptance rate into a vector, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack...but nonetheless a solution:

```
output = capture.output(MCMClogit(y ~ x, burnin = 5000, mcmc = 1000,
                                  tune = 1.3, B0 = 0, verbose = TRUE))

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

output %>%
  paste0(collapse = "") %>%
  str_extract("\\d+[.]\\d+(?=[@])") %>%
  as.numeric()

# [1] "0.45533"
```

This uses `capture.output` to store what's printed in the console from your `MCMClogit` in a variable as a string, then uses regex to extract the acceptance rate. What makes the regex relatively easy is that the acceptance rate is surrounded by `@`'s.

OP made a good point that by using this method, `MCMClogit` will have to be run twice, which is not desirable if the model takes a really long time to run. One thing that can be done is to use `<<-` (could be dangerous), and assign the model into `m` in the global environment:

```
output = capture.output(m <<- MCMClogit(y ~ x, burnin = 5000, mcmc = 1000,
                                        tune = 1.3, B0 = 0, verbose = TRUE))
```

This way, the model object will be stored in `m` and the console output will be stored in `output` simultaneously.

Also note that `<<-` actually assigns variables in the parent environment. In this case, where there is only one function, the parent environment is the global environment. However, in the case where there are nested functions, the parent environment would be one level above the nest and so one should use `assign` instead:

```
output = capture.output(assign("m", MCMClogit(y ~ x, burnin = 5000, mcmc = 1000,
                                              tune = 1.3, B0 = 0, verbose = TRUE),
                               envir = globalenv()))
```

Comment: Thanks - so the `mcmc` object is lost in this, if I am correct? The code would need to be run twice then.

Comment: @tomka Good point. See my edits. I really wish someone could figure out a better way though, since I often hesitate to use `<<-` inside a function.

Comment: Can you specify what is dangerous about it?

Comment: @tomka In this case you should be fine, but in some other cases, you could unexpectedly change a global variable when you don't mean to or end up in a situation where you reference a global variable within a function when you actually wanted to reference a variable passed in as a parameter.